# Comparing huge range of cells and one column from two different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

There are two different worksheets, and I want to highlight cells in sheet1 that match exact same text value in sheet2.

Sheet1 is a daily Production Plan, so there are [Name, the number of order, Explianation] along with 14 days columns.

Sheet2 is a list of products which we supply material for. I couldn't find exact same situation when I googled. I tried to write a code below, but it doesn't work.

In Sheet2, list of products is located in Column 'C', and I have 1582 items.
Your help will be really appreciated.

```
Sub Highlights()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim lastRowNumber As Long, lastColumnNumber As Long

    lastRowNumber = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    lastColumnNumber = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
    For j = 1 To lastRowNumber
        For i = 1 To lastColumnNumber
            For x = 3 To 1584
                If sh1.Cells(j & i) = sh2.Cells(x, 3) Then
                    sh1.Cells(j, i).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 49407
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
               End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Main reason your code doesn't work is `sh1.Cells(j & i)` should be `sh1.Cells(j, i)`.  That said,  this will be hideously slow for a data set of any size.  Consider converting to a Variant Array approach.  Plenty of examples here on SO

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to conditionally shade cells, you can accomplish this without looping.

First, make sure both tables are formatted as tables (Home > Format as Table).  In this example, the table I want to highlight is named "t_Stuff", the table containing the criteria is named "t_StuffCriteria" and the column containing the criteria is named "Colors".

- Go to Home > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > Add a New Rule > Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format
- Then add this formula

(replacing the table names and column name with your own info:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("t_StuffCriteria"),INDIRECT("t_Stuff[@[Colors]]"))>0
```

- Click Format and choose how you'd like your cells formatted.

  - Click Okay > Okay
  - In the Applies To box, highlight all of the cells in the table where highlight should be applied, then click Apply.

[image]

[image]

Here is the result.  The entire row of the first table is highlighted if any cell in the row matches any cell in the second table's specified column.

[image]

Or, if you want to keep it strictly vba...

```
Sub ConditionalFormatEntireRow_BasedOnCellMatch()

'~~~> Declare the variables
Dim wsT As Worksheet 'name of the sheet with data to be tested
Dim wsC As Worksheet 'name of the sheet with the criteria
Dim t As ListObject 'table name containing data to be tested
Dim c As ListObject 'table name with the criteria
Dim tCol As Long 'column name with the criteria
Dim f As String 'formula to be used for conditional formatting
Dim fc As FormatCondition
Dim i As Integer

'~~~> Turn off screen updating and alerts.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


'~~~> Inputs.  Modify these with your values.-----------------------------------
'~~~> Store your objects as variables.
Set wsT = Worksheets("Conditional Format")
Set wsC = Worksheets("Conditional Format") 'my example tables are on the same sheet
Set t = wsT.ListObjects("t_Stuff")
Set c = wsC.ListObjects("t_StuffCriteria")
tCol = t.ListColumns("Colors").Index
f = "=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""" & c.Name & """),INDIRECT(""" & _
    t.Name & "[@[" & t.ListColumns(tCol).Name & "]]""))>0"
'~~~> End of inputs.------------------------------------------------------------

'~~~> Double check the formula variable.
If f = "=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(""t_StuffCriteria""),INDIRECT(""t_Stuff[@[Colors]]""))>0" Then

    Debug.Print "The formula is correct."

End If

With t.Range

    '~~~> Delete any existing formatting conditions.
    .FormatConditions.Delete

    '~~~> Set the format conditions.
    Set fc = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:=f)

        '~~~> Specify the formatting that should be applied.
        With fc

            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = vbGreen
            .StopIfTrue = False

        End With

End With

'~~~> Turn on screen updating and alerts.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'~~~> Release the variables from memory.
Set wsT = Nothing
Set wsC = Nothing
Set t = Nothing
Set c = Nothing
tCol = Null
f = vbNullString
Set fc = Nothing

End Sub
```